# User's Facebook Status to tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, uitableview

I am newbie to Facebook app development, and have done some research but cant seem to find what I am looking for. Here's what I am trying to do.

I am trying to create an app that one part of it displays a facebook user's past statuses into a tableview from most recent to oldest. And inside the app be able to Save their favorite statuses to a Favorites page.-- I have a pretty good idea on how i would save the favorite statuses, however the problem that I am having is getting the statuses from facebook to the app.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or help me out it would be much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try the following code ..... provide a limit


     NSString * pRequestString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/statuses?limit=100%@",[FBSession activeSession].accessToken];

    [[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:pRequestString2] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"%@",result);

        }];


                                 or

try this ....

 NSString * pRequestString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/feed?%@",[FBSession activeSession].accessToken];

[[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:pRequestString2] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",result);

    }];



make sure you have proper permissions .....
```